# Query to match primary key from Customer table and CustomerCard based on CustomerEmail and CustomerCardNumber?

Tags: sql, oracle

[Here's an image that shows these tables in Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv3D4.png)

I'm trying to do a query that updates Customer's Card information based on Customer's email and Customer's Card Number. "Customers" is a table and "CustomerCards" is another table and both of these tables are related. Both have CustomerID as Primary Key. So the data inputed for the query from a webservice is the Customer's Email and CustomerCard's number. So lets say the email is "test123@gmail.com" and the cardnumber is "1234567". With only this information I need to do an update query on CustomerCards but CustomerCards table doesn't have email attribute. I'm imagining an inner join is needed but I have no clue how I can do this.

Here's an example of the update query that works if I insert the customerid but now i need to do this with customer's email that is not an attribute from CustomerCards table.

`query = "update customercards set expirationmonth='" + expirationmonth + "', expirationyear='" + expirationyear +
                "' where cardnumber='"+ cardNumber + "' and customerid='" + emailPersonal + "'";`

Comment: Which column do you want to update in the `CustomersCards` table?

Comment: In this case the expiration month and expiration year, I updated the post that shows the working query with CustomerId, now I need to this exactly with Customers' email  that is an attribute from Customers table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle does not support the `UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET` syntax. Instead, you can use a subquery to recover the customer id from the email:

```
UPDATE CustomerCards
SET 
    expirationMonth = :expirationMonth
    expirationyear  = :expirationYear
WHERE
    CardNumber = :cardNumber
    AND cc.CustomerId = (SELECT CustomerId FROM Customers c WHERE email = :email)
```

This assumes that there an email uniquely identify a customer.

The query expects 4 parameters:

- `:cardNumber` and `:email` are used to identify the record to update
- `:expirationMonth` and `:expirationYear` are the vaues to assign

Comment: Probably a fair assumption but just pointing out this assumes one customer per email

Comment: @kjmerf: yes, it should be... I mentionned it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks both for answering! I'll try out both of them and see which works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Would be something like:

```
UPDATE CustomerCards
SET CardNumber = '1234567'
WHERE CustomerID = (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE Email = 'test123@gmail.com')
```

Adjust as needed. The above will update the card number to 1234567 for the customer associated with the email address test123@gmail.com

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! My only question is why is the TOP 1 needed in this case?